# dateTime stored in database in UTC, but when reading as C# objects it's automatically converted to Local Time, I want UTC only, how?

Tags: c#, datetime

In database I am storing the datetime in UTC,

[image]

I have class property like below,

```
public DateTime CollectionTimeUtc { get; set; }
```

Now when I am reading from database into C# object, it's automatically converted back to local time,

[image]

How to avoid this conversion ? I want it UTC. Thanks!

Comment: use [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset) instead of `DateTime`?

Comment: or you need some kind of value converters, depending on your ORM. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions#configuring-a-value-converter) is an example for EF Core.

Comment: @vasily.sib, DateTimeOffset works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own explicit getter and setter, like the old way of writing properties in C#.

```
private DateTime collectionTimeUtc;

public DateTime CollectionTimeUtc
{
    get { return collectionTimeUtc; }
    set { collectionTimeUtc = value.ToUniversalTime(); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.